# sql server insert data into table dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table A that has call count number of employees for last 30 days. However, if the employee does't have call for last 30 days, it won't show up in this table. How can I insert those employee into this table (say employee list is in table B)

```
Table A:

Employee  Date  Call_count
Jim        20180224   10
Jim        20180223   10
Jim        20180222   10
....
Jock        20180224   12
Jock        20180223   12
Jock        20180222   101
...
```

Table B only has employee names:

```
    Employee
    Jim
    Jock
    Ann
```

Expected result( say Ann is the one who doesn't have calls):

```
Employee  Date  Call_count
Jim        20180224   10
Jim        20180223   10
Jim        20180222   10
....
Jock        20180224   12
Jock        20180223   12
Jock        20180222   101
...
Ann         20180224   0
Ann         20180223   0
Ann        20180222   0
```

Comment: did u tried using `insert` into table ?

Comment: how are your constructing Table A? Is it not a result of some query?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a calendar table, then this becomes a pretty basic query:

```
SELECT  b.Employee,
        c.Date,
        Call_count = ISNULL(a.Call_count, 0) 
FROM    dbo.Calendar AS c
        CROSS JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TableA AS a
            ON a.Date = c.[Date]
            AND a.Employee = b.Employee  
WHERE   c.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
AND     c.Date < GETDATE();
```

The key being you first generate a full set of all cominations of dates and names, then `LEFT JOIN` to your data, so now you are not limited to results that exist in `TableA`.

If you don't have a calendar table, then you can generate a list of dates on the fly. Much more reading about this is here:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Part 3 is specifically relevant as it deals with dates.

But for simplicity to get a list of the last 30 days you can generate a list of number from 1-30 using this:

```
SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n1.n), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
FROM    (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n1 (n) 
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n2 (n);
```

There are 3 steps here.

1. Use [table value constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) to create a set of 6 rows and a set of 6 rows, and cross join them to get 30 rows.
2. Use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to create a sequential id for each row.
3. Subtract this number from today's date to get a list of the last 30 days.

You can now substitute this set into the query above in place of the calenar table:

```
WITH Calendar AS
(   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n1.n), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
    FROM    (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n1 (n) 
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n2 (n)
)
SELECT  b.Employee,
        c.Date,
        Call_count = ISNULL(a.Call_count, 0) 
FROM    Calendar AS c
        CROSS JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TableA AS a
            ON a.Date = c.[Date]
            AND a.Employee = b.Employee ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert` with Filter clause. This will be more accurate if you have any `id` column instead of looking on `name` column

```
insert into tableA ( Employee, date,call_count)

select employee, date , 0 call_count from Tableb where employee not in 
(select employee from from tableA)
```

Comment: thanks but Table B only has employee name, it doesn't have any other data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
Insert into table A (employee,date,call_count)
Select employee,date,call_count from table B where isnull(call_count,0)<>0
```

Comment: thanks but Table B only has employee name, it doesn't have any other data